# 2nd level model compilation

Tags: angularjs

I have the following model:

```
{
  content: "Hello world, this is a sample content",
  notes: {
    content: "side note, some text here.",
    index: 2
  }
}
```

I like the above model to be compiled to the following HTML:

```
<div class="content">
    Hello world,*
    <div class="note">side note, some text here.</div>
    this is a sample text. 
</div>
```

How can this be done?
As far as I know the best way is to use directive, like `<div content="{{ content }}"></div>`.
I tried to write this directive and use the compile service without much success yet...

I want to inject the note compiled with its HTML to the content after the second word (see the note index position is 2).

I have here two templates, one for the content and the second for the note. I want to compile the note with its view and then enter it to the content text after the second work. Then, I'd like so compile the content against its view.

Answer (score 2):

I think I follow. The notes will be styled to look like margin notes or as a tooltip, right?

This should be pretty easy to accomplish in a directive. I'd instantiate it like this (though implementation details are up to you):

```html
<div note-section 
  note="{{notes.content}}" 
  note-index="{{notes.index}}" 
  content="{{content}}">
</div>
```

Alright. Then, within your link function, you have access to all of these attributes. So then I would $watch for changes, and when they occur, search the `scope.content` string for the appropriate index where `scope.noteIndex` words lives, and then slice the string into two pieces, inserting a note template like follows between it:

```js
var tmpl, childElement;

tmpl = beforeNote + '<span note="{{note}}"></span>' + afterNote;
childElement = $compile( tmpl )( scope );

element.append( childElement );
```

The `note` element is a directive that has an isolate scope (for security).

Then the rendered DOM node would match your goal above. This is very generic and there are zillions of variations that depend on your implementation, but this is the general pattern I'd follow.

Take a stab at it on Plunker or jsFiddle, and post what you come up with!

Comment: Why do you suggest to separate this for two directives? Is there any security issue if the content is trusted?

Comment: @FitzchakYitzchaki Sorry for the confusion. The separate directive is for extensibility; the isolate scope is for security. These are just best practices. I would use a separate directive so that the  implementation (e.g. template) is separate from the logic for extensibility reasons. For the security, it's not a question of "trusted content", but the worry that a variable or function on your directive's scope will be the same as on the parent's scope and therefore overwrite it by accident. Isolate scopes are for scope security.

Answer (score 0):

Question: Why does the note have to appear in the HTML at a particular position (index), why can't it always appear before or after? Is there a specific reason, or is this to support styling?

If you are trying to support styling, there are better and easier ways to accomplish this, such as using `float: right`, etc.

As far as I know, there is no built in way to accomplish such output.
If you must have that specific HTML, you can try the following jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/69ApD/.

Comment: This works, but it ties your DOM and data together, which we shouldn't do. I would also be cautious about putting too much implementation (like the templating) in the directive logic as it makes it less portable.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to support styling, and using `float: right` on the `note` class. The issue that in order to achieve the visual effect that I want, the floated div should be in that location.

Comment: I wanted to show how such HTML could be achieved, and I think our answers complement each other, @JoshDavidMiller. I would work harder on the styling, in order to avoid such a requirement altogther.

Comment: I would too, but I don't see any way around this.